# Where is the background image column in SearchManager?

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-tv

I could not find any column to set background image inside SearchManager class. 
When Google Play app's search result is selected, a background image is displayed but I don't seem to find any public api/column to set it.

Here is my code for content provider's query method
Any idea guys?

Device: Nexus player

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    final String searchKey = (selectionArgs == null) ? "" : selectionArgs[0];
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchKey)) {
        // Get title list from search query
        ArrayList<TitleSimpleInfo> searchedTitleList = searchTitlesWithKeyword(searchKey);
        // return null cursor if no data found
        if (searchedTitleList == null || searchedTitleList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        // prepare cursor
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_CONTENT_TYPE,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_RESULT_CARD_IMAGE,
        });
        // add search result to cursor
        for (TitleSimpleInfo title : searchedTitleList) {
            matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{
                    title.getTitleName(),
                    title.getTitleCatch(),
                    SEARCH_CONTENT_TYPE,
                    Intent.ACTION_SEARCH,
                    SEARCH_INTENT_DATA + title.getTitleCode(),
                    SEARCH_IMAGE_HEADER + title.getThumbnailUrl(),
            });
        }
        return matrixCursor;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Lean Back` Library ?